# Git integration in visual studio broken

Tags: visual-studio-2008, git, msysgit, git-extensions

Using visual studio 2008, 9.0.30729.1 SP1
Installed (msys) git, git versin 1.6.5.1.1367.gcd48, git-gui 0.12.0.23.ga91be.

i have the GIT menu in the menu bar, and git icons in the toolbar, but clicking them doesn't have any effect any more. It worked before, on my previous laptop. But that was probably a (little) older git version, and may be little different vs2008. For sure it was vista before, and (64 bit) win 7 now.

it may have broken during install of VS 2008 SP1. I've tried reinstalling Git. 
i also considered problems with the repository i copied from the old laptop. but renaming the .git dir didn't help.
Even the Git-About Git Extensions menu item doesn't work.
the buttons in the taskbar activate and deactivate as they should on loading and closing projects however.
last thing i considered windows opening outside the screen (laptop config, with changing screen setup) but alt-tab doesn't show antyhing.

Ideas are welcome!

Comment: did you try upgrading git-extensions? http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/downloads/list

Comment: For anyone else who runs across this - as of the latest release (v2.02), the menu items will only work when a project or file is selected in the Solution Explorer - not when the solution itself is selected.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select a project or file in the solution explorer, then it kicks in to life.